# Adding an ipv6 address to "require ip" in phpmyadmin.conf in linux

Tags: linux, ipv6, centos6

I'm trying to edit `phpMyAdmin.conf` in `etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` such that it only allows an ip.
I have this which works when my router is set to only allow ipv4 addresses:

```
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 111.222.333.444
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 111.222.333.444
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
```

I want to add an ipv6 address, but it only works when I add an entire ipv6 address (replacing ::1).  ie `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:b95:bdb0:9c2b`

However, my ipv6 address changes on reboot.  So I want to add a limited address.

I've tried:
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx?
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:*
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/48
and all the variants of the above.

but none work (in fact, phpmyadmin won't restart)

Is there a way to do this?  Thanks :)

Comment: Any error message in your webserver error log?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The supported syntaxes are, for Apache 2.2 and 2.4 respectively:

```
Allow from 1111:2222:3333:4444::/64

Require ip 1111:2222:3333:4444::/64
```

The syntax you were trying was probably missing the terminal `::`, which was causing the base IPv6 address to be invalid. (It'd be comparable to trying to write `1.2.3/24` instead of `1.2.3.0/24`.)

Comment: @DanielFrancis Welcome to [so]. When your problem is solved, remember to click on the tick mark next to the answer that solved your problem, to mark it as solved.

Comment: Realizing this is VERY old thread, for completeness sake (and because I happen to have stumbled across this thread); Allow, Deny and Order are (to be) deprecated; https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html